# Ecommerce site on VM Webserver Ubuntu Linux Apache2 problem connection outside

Tags: apache

I've been going crazy for a week because I can not get my ecommerce site done with prestashop outside my LAN network.

I'll explain to you better

I have a vmware webserver machine Ubuntu 16.04, above I installed LAMP (apache, mysq, php ...) with static ip address 192.168.1.x and public address x.x.x.x

---> from local the site is ok (/ var / www / html / SiteFolder), I have configured the nat on the modem so that connections to x.x.x.x go directly to 192.168.1.x

---> I registered on dynDNS.it and I matched a name to the x.x.x.x "A NAME OF THE SITE"

---> when I access from the outside to latanadinix.homepc.it I see the folders and files in / var / www / html /, but when I click on / SiteFolder says "time for the connection exhausted", I notice that the url is not it is more "MY SITE NAME" but 192.168.1.x / sitefolder / index.php

i do not know why !!!

the owner of the folder in / var / www / html is www-data
I tried to set in /etc/apache2 / sites-avaibles and sites -able documentroot / var / www / html / sitefolder
but nothing ...

I really do not understand what the problem is ...

HEEEELPPPP PLS :)

Comment: Looks like your implementation performs an external redirection to the internal server address which obviously won't work. Most likely the implementation tries to "guess" the server name, fails, and falls back to the only thing it knows: the address. I suggest you configure the correct `ServerName` in your http servers host configuration.

Comment: And stop panicking and changing file system permissions. Instead calm down and think. You have nothing that indicates a file system permission issue. But you do observe that the URL in the browser is changed in a way you do not expect. So that is the thing you should concentrate on.

Comment: i'm concentrating on the strange url that changes precisely, it was to give you all the information about it.
do I have to configure the hosts file in / etc?

Comment: in /etc/hosts i've got 
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ubuntu (name of my server)
x.x.x.x   latanadinix.homepc.it www.latanadinix.homepc.it
is it wrong?

Comment: I precisely told you in my first document that you probably forgot to change the `ServerName` that your http server uses. So that is something you have to configure inside the http server configuration, it is not a system setting.

Comment: One remark: it appears that you do not really have an idea what you are doing, that you have a huge lack of understanding in network technology. Are you really sure that you see yourself fit to operate a public web shop given that situation? Isn't the risk you take too big? You need to consider that people will obviously try to manipulate your shop. Are you really sure that you can prevent and detect that? I doubt it, sorry. Maybe you should step back and learn a few more things first.